# Updating a parameter's value doesn't update the result of the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm completely new to programming...

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = 1
S = sum(L[0:n])

while n < 5:
    n += 1

print(n)  # output: 5
print(S)  # output: 1
```

Why does python not change the parameter `n` in the `sum` function while it does change `n` itself? Can someone explain the logic behind that and show me a way to change `n` in the `sum` function so that `S` becomes 15 instead of 1?

Comment: You called `sum` one time, and stored the value that it returns in `S`. If you want a new sum, you  have to call `sum` again. Python variables aren't like spreadsheet cells that automatically update themselves whenever anything else changes. (If you want that, you may want to look at, say, Prolog instead of Python.)

Comment: You may want to google "imperative programming".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is an [imperative programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming). This means that a python program is a series of *statements* that can change the program's state (for example by assigning a value to a variable). Once a statement has been executed, it no longer has an effect on the program. In other words: The statement can change the program's state, but only once.

When you execute the statement `S = sum(L[0:n])`, `sum(L[0:n])` is *evaluated* and the result is assigned to the variable `S`. `L[0:n]` evaluates to `[1]`, and the sum of `[1]` is 1. So at the end of this statement, the value of `S` is the number 1.

Your misconception is that `S` "remembers" that it is equal to `sum(L[0:n])`, but that is not the case. `S` is just the number 1. It doesn't matter if you change the value of `n` or `L`; the number 1 stays the number 1. If you want `S` to change, you have to *explicitly* update it with another assignment statement:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = 1
S = sum(L[0:n])

while n < 5:
    n += 1
    S = sum(L[0:n])

print(n)  # output: 5
print(S)  # output: 15
```

---

Side note: Languages in which `S` would automatically be updated when `n` changes are called [declarative programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming).

Answer (score 2):

It evaluates `S = sum(L[0:n])` only at the beginning, it isn't a function that is updated. One way to change this is to re-evaluate S after you update n:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = 1

while n < 5:
    n += 1
    S = sum(L[0:n])
    print(n, S)
```