# Variable doesn't get updated in if else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
price = input("How much: ") 
country = input("which country are you from :")
tax = 0
total = int(price) + (int(price)*(tax/100)) 


if country =="Canada" : 

   province = input("Which province? :")
   if province == "Alberta" :
       tax = 5
       print(total)
   elif province == "Ontario" : 
       tax = 13
       print(total)
   else : 
       tax = 11
       print(total)
else : 
     tax = 0
     print(total)
```

This code does not update the tax and doesn't calculate total afterward accordingly. Can anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: You need to calculate the total *after* setting the tax value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating a parameter's value doesn't update the result of the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49587299/updating-a-parameters-value-doesnt-update-the-result-of-the-function)

Comment: Create a function for total like get_total(tax,price) etc that returns total value given tax and price in input and call that whenever you update tax.

Comment: Tbh, you need a good datastructure to save your data. Possibly a json-stucture (dictionary)

Comment: The code worked setting the tax value then calculating the total. Thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you are calculating `total` before changing `tax` to be the correct value. You can fix this by moving the calculation so that it happens after `tax` has been set.

```
price = input("How much: ")
country = input("which country are you from :")
tax = 0

if country == "Canada":
    province = input("Which province? :")
    if province == "Alberta":
        tax = 5
    elif province == "Ontario":
        tax = 13
    else:
        tax = 11
else:
    tax = 0

total = int(price) + (int(price)*(tax/100))
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is, you pre-calculated the `total` before the if statement with `tax = 0`. That would always return the same value. 
Try calculating the total everytime you update the tax. 
Something like this:

```
tax = 5
total = int(price) + (int(price)*(tax/100)) 
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this simple example. I think it can help you "rethink" your data-sctructure. Good luck!

```
taxes = {
    'Canada': {
        'Alberta': 5,
        'Ontario': 13,
        'default': 11
    }
}

def taxfunc(price, tax):
    return price + price*tax/100

price = int(input("How much: "))
country = input("which country are you from :").title()

if country in taxes:
    province = input("Which province? :").title()
    tax = taxfunc(price, taxes[country].get(province, taxes[country]['default']))
    print('Your tax is: {}'.format(tax))
else:
    print('no data')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try your method and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: After getting the `tax`, then calculate the `total`. Problem of your code is you calculate the `total` before assigning values to `tax`. Always your `total` is for `tax = 0` only. But moving the `total` calculation to the bottom will fix the issue.

```
price = input("How much: ") 
country = input("which country are you from :")
tax = 0        

if country =="Canada" :     
   province = input("Which province? :")
   if province == "Alberta" :
       tax = 5
   elif province == "Ontario" : 
       tax = 13
   else : 
       tax = 11
else : 
   tax = 0

total = int(price) + (int(price)*(tax/100))
print(total)
```