# Method attribute is not updating itself even though I'm clearly assigning a different value to it

Tags: python, class

Upon updating a value, the `__init__` method still uses the old attribute value.

```
class Email:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.email = self.name + "@hotmail.com"

    def details(self):
        return f'{self.name} | {self.email}'

person = Email("James")
print(person.details())

person.name = "Michael"
print(person.details())
```

Output gotten:

```
James | James@hotmail.com
Michael | James@hotmail.com
```

Output expected:

```
James | James@hotmail.com
Michael | Michael@hotmail.com
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related, maybe dupe: [Updating a parameter's value doesn't update the result of the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49587299/updating-a-parameters-value-doesnt-update-the-result-of-the-function)

Comment: It changed the `name` as you told it.  Nothing in your code creates a new `email` once the instance was created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What went wrong in the OP?

If we open up the `person` object right after you instantiated it with the line `person = Email("James")`, it would be something like this:

```
person {
"name"  : "James", 
"email" : "James@hotmail.com"
}
```

If we update the `name` variable in this `person` object as you did with `person.name = "Michael"`, and open up the `person` object again, it would be:

```
person {
"name"  : "Michael", 
"email" : "James@hotmail.com"
}
```

Please note that at this stage, it is still the same `person` object we instantiated earlier, and the `email` variable is not changed from its previous state, because we didn't do anything about it, yet.

---

[The answer posted by @chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54737793/7613480) is very nice and clean, by setting `email` field as a `property`, and by setting it dynamically using the `name` variable. Below is a copy of @chepner 's code:

```
class Email:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        # self.email = self.name + "@hotmail.com"

    @property
    def email(self):
        return f'{self.name}@hotmail.com'

    def details(self):
        return f'{self.name} | {self.email}'
```

---

### What is `property` and how is it used?

`property` is a Python [Built-in Function](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property), a `property` object has these methods:

- `getter`: used to get an attribute value
- `setter`: used to set an attribute value
- `deleter`: used to delete an attribute value

---

Now, what exactly is happening in [@chepner 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54737793/7613480)? With the lines below, we are setting the `email` as a `property`:

```
    @property
    def email(self):
        return f'{self.name}@hotmail.com'
```

And this decorated function can also be used as a `getter`, e.g. `person.email`.

Note that in here we didn't link it to a variable (as shown in the [Python documentation example](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property)), if we want / need, we can do so by replacing the `return` statement and set an `_email` variable in `__init__`:

```
    def __init__(self, input_name):
        self._name = input_name
        self._email = f'{self._name}@hotmail.com'

    @property
    def email(self):
        return self._email
```

And then, as for the `setter` and `deleter`, we can create them as:

```
    @email.setter
    def email(self, input_email):
        self._email = input_email

    @email.deleter
    def email(self):
        del self._email
```

Note that the `getter`, `setter`, and `deleter` methods all have the same name as the `property`, just different decorators.

From the question description it is not needed to support updating the email address separately, but just following this example here, if we run `person.email = "Michael@hotmail.com"`, because `email` is a `property`, it is triggering the `setter` to set the value to the `_email` variable.

---

Going back to the `details` method in [@chepner 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54737793/7613480):

```
    def details(self):
        return f'{self.name} | {self.email}'
```

By doing `self.email` we are triggering the `getter` to return the email address, which is dynamically generated in that `return` statement `return f'{self.name}@hotmail.com'`.

Comment: Nice answer, but the one thing I don't like is that you're explaining another person's (chepner's) answer without even linking to it. I guarantee that nobody will bother to scroll down to find the answer you're talking about. I think it'd be a big improvement if you copied the relevant code into your answer. (It's not like chepner has an exclusive copyright on trivial getter functions, after all.) Then your answer would be 100% complete.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks for the comment, and thanks for pointing out the missing part! I did copy from his code but only two separate functions, I'll make the changes to add the link.

Comment: `property` is `class`, not `built_in_function`. Your link is right, but the text of link is not right.

Comment: @LiuXiMin Thanks for the comment! I respectfully stand by my answer. If you open the link, the web page title says built-in-functions. Also I agree `property` is a `class` itself, but in this context, I'm describing it as a built-in function.

Comment: @UdonN00dle Okay, It is not a big problem. Callable object in Python is just alike function after all :-)

Answer (score 6):

In this example, `self.email` is being assigned in the `__init__` method of the class, which is only called when an instance of `Email` is created. As such, when `self.name` is reassigned, `self.email` is not changed. To work around this, you can use a `property` decorator:

```
class Email:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self._name = name
    self._email = f'{name}@hotmail.com'
  def details(self):
    return f'{self._name} | {self._email}'
  @property
  def name(self):
    return self._name
  @name.setter
  def name(self, _new_name):
    self._name = _new_name
    self._email = f'{_new_name}@hotmail.com'

person = Email("James")
print(person.details())
person.name = "Michael"
print(person.details())
```

Output:

```
James | James@hotmail.com
Michael | Michael@hotmail.com
```

Comment: Making `email` the property, computing the e-mail address on demand based on the current name, would be a lot simpler and more in line with the expectation of the original question.

Comment: I just wraped my head around it, I understand what's happening there, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The simplest fix would be to make `email` a property, rather than an attribute you set in `__init__`.

```
class Email:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        # self.email = self.name + "@hotmail.com"

    @property
    def email(self):
        return f'{self.name}@hotmail.com'

    def details(self):
        return f'{self.name} | {self.email}'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It took me awhile but I think I got it, the __init__ method was only being executed upon the creation of an object, therefore the attribute email was not being updated even if I changed the name attribute, but by creating its own method with @property I am able to call it as an attribute and force an update by grabbing the value from __init__ , right?

Comment: Yes; `email` is no longer a fixed value, but computed on demand using whatever `name` currently is.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ajax1234 saying, the init function is calling when you create a new instance. Think it like a constructor if you are familiar with an object oriented language.

So, if you just change the person.name, you can change the name field but not the email variable which assigned with older value of name.

You have a few options about that case:

- You can create a new Email object with name of Michael.
- You can re-assign the e-mail directly, like you do in init function.
- You can create a "setter" method for name like `setName(name)` and you can update the email in this function. So, when you call the setter, it automatically updates the email.